# IE 7, 8 AJAX focus bug

Tags: internet-explorer

When loading content via ajax in IE 7, 8 (NOT IE 9, safari, chrome, firefox) and calling $("#item").focus(), it doesn't actually grab focus in IE 7, IE 8. Is there a way to fix this? Should try setTimeout then focus? (which seems like a hack)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me.

**setTimeout** seems to work for certain scenarios.

http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/focus-is-not-working-in-ie-solution/